# why browsers editing shortcut is the same as emacs default shortcut?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Things like ctrl-a , ctrl-e , ctrl-f, ctrl-b, ctrl-n, ctrl-p, ctrl-k, ctrl-d.

When you edit in a normal html form in any browser I know (IE not included), the shortcuts above works the same as in emacs ?

(When I say normal form , I mean a html form without any interactive js stuff. )

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I think this is an open-ended question with no practical answer. There are many applications/frameworks (Cocoa, for example) that use Emacs keybindings extensively.

Comment: It's not true, anyway.  `Ctrl+A` is generally "Select All", etc.  But I wish it worked that way.  I hate leaving my emacs keybindings.

Comment: It seems to be somewhat true on Linux and Mac, where some other Linux/Mac apps also use Emacs-based keybindings. It's not true on Windows, where ctrl- keys are used for Windows shortcuts.

Comment: @DanielMartín thank you guys answering. I thought there might be some kind of historical reason like the first powerful browser is made by some emacs hackers, so no questions they put the emacs keybindings into it . Firefox? what was it called back at that time.

Comment: @harpo, "Select All" is `Cmd+A`.

Comment: @katspaugh, yes, on a Mac.  I was using the PC term like the OP.  The real way to say it of course is `C-a`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your browser uses the readline library. The keybindings depend on the OS Actually. You can even configure the keybindings editing the ~/.inputrc file. You can read more at [the readline manual here](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html)

Answer (score 10):

Because these are the key-bindings that God intended for us to use.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @sjas:  hmm... really?

Comment: Yes. See the accepted answer which is spot on. I love using emacs and its bindings, too, but that ain't making your answer more right.